# Error occurred during jest unit testing of Echarts(setOption) in the Angular

Tags: angular, jestjs, echarts

When initializing UT on components, an error occurred when the test code ran to **fixture.deteChanges()**
component.ts↓

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     this.initChartOption();
}
```

```
public initChartOption(): void {
     const chartDom = document.getElementById('line-chart');
     const myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
     this.chart = myChart;
     myChart.setOption(this.chartOption);
     ......
}
```

console error↓

```
myChart.setOption(this.chartOption);
        ^
TypeError:Cannot set properties of undefined (setting "dpr")
```

Jest-canvas-mock has been imported

Do you have any experience in solving similar problems？Please help me as it has been bothering me for half a month now

I mocked the dom in beforeEach, but it didn't work

```
const chartDom = document.createElement('div')
chartDom.id = 'line-chart';
document.body.appendChild(chartDom);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
beforeEach(()=>{
    jest.spyOn(echarts, 'init').mockImplementation(() => ({
        setOption: jest.fn(),
        resize: jest.fn(),
        dispatchAction: jest.fn()
    } as any));
})
```